# Asigning Correct package as per class uses

Tags: java, web-services

I have a java web service application, having two packages.

`com.demo.webappl.dao`  <= contains the Data Access Object classes.

`com.demo.webappl.dto`  <= contains the data transfer Object Classes.

But there are some other POJO classes which are used in commonly in these `dto` and `dao` classes, logically what should I name  that pages which contains POJO classes which are neither `dao` nor `dto`.

Comment: sorry if attached wrong tags. but didnt get good  suggestion for these type of question

Answer (score 0):

Usually, objects that you use to share data across different layers of your program classify under `dto`. These classes sometimes are left in the "root" package (`com.demo.webappl`). For objects with are used internally in a single package can be left in the package itself (`com.demo.webappl.module1`).

For better clarity, try checking your organization or the framework's coding standards/guidelines.